Fetch the Name based diff version for same Service and Function
Here is my Json object .
[
 {
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Asset A",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Song",
  "Service": "Song"
 },
 {
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Asse B",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "IndustryX",
  "Service": "IndustryX"
 },
 {
  "Id": 3,
  "Name": "Asse C",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Strategy",
  "Service": "IndustryX"
 },
 {
  "Id": 4,
  "Name": "Asse D",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Strategy",
  "Service": "IndustryX"
 },
 {
  "Id": 5,
  "Name": "Asse D",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Cross Function",
  "Service": "IndustryX"
 },
 {
  "Id": 6,
  "Name": "Asse E",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Cross Function",
  "Service": "IndustryX"
 },
 {
  "Id": 7,
  "Name": "Asse F",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Cross Function",
  "Service": "Song"
 },
 {
  "Id": 8,
  "Name": "Asse G",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Cross Function",
  "Service": "Song"
 },
 {
  "Id": 9,
  "Name": "Asse G",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Strategy",
  "Service": "Song"
 },
 {
  "Id": 10,
  "Name": "Asse H",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Strategy",
  "Service": "Song"
 },
 {
  "Id": 11,
  "Name": "Asse A",
  "Version": 2,
  "Function": "Strategy",
  "Service": "Song"
 },
 {
  "Id": 12,
  "Name": "Asse A",
  "Version": 1,
  "Function": "Cross Function",
  "Service": "Song"
 }
]

select Name and Version when Service is 'IndustrYx' and Function is neither IndustryX nor Cross Function for that AssetVersion.
select Name and Version when Service is 'Song' and Function is neither Song nor Cross Function for that AssetVersion.
Expected Output : 3,10 ,11 record should come.
Here Asset D with version 1 has 2 record, if either 'Cross Function' or 'IndusryX' present for that Version and Name, should not appear in list
Tried but did not work

What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

what did you tried, how you want to see result? list og objects, list of nodes?... show what you tried.

Need list of object.  Here Input is nothing but my List of object that passing as Input.                                                                                                                  List assetcheck= Input.Where(a => a.Service == "Song" && a.Function != "Song"
|| a.Function != "Cross Function").ToList();

You can refer my sample code below, here is my test result.

public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    var assets = new List<Request>
    {
        new Request { Id = 1, Name = "Asset A", Version = 1, Function = "Song", Service = "Song" },
        new Request { Id = 2, Name = "Asse B", Version = 1, Function = "IndustryX", Service = "IndustryX" },
        new Request { Id = 3, Name = "Asse C", Version = 1, Function = "Strategy", Service = "IndustryX" },
        new Request { Id = 4, Name = "Asse D", Version = 1, Function = "Strategy", Service = "IndustryX" },
        new Request { Id = 5, Name = "Asse D", Version = 1, Function = "Cross Function", Service = "IndustryX" },
        new Request { Id = 6, Name = "Asse E", Version = 1, Function = "Cross Function", Service = "IndustryX" },
        new Request { Id = 7, Name = "Asse F", Version = 1, Function = "Cross Function", Service = "Song" },
        new Request { Id = 8, Name = "Asse G", Version = 1, Function = "Cross Function", Service = "Song" },
        new Request { Id = 9, Name = "Asse G", Version = 1, Function = "Strategy", Service = "Song" },
        new Request { Id = 10, Name = "Asse H", Version = 1, Function = "Strategy", Service = "Song" },
        new Request { Id = 11, Name = "Asse A", Version = 2, Function = "Strategy", Service = "Song" },
        new Request { Id = 12, Name = "Asse A", Version = 1, Function = "Cross Function", Service = "Song" }
    };

    var filteredAssets = assets
        .GroupBy(a => new { a.Name, a.Version })
        .Where(g => !g.Any(a => a.Function == "IndustryX" || a.Function == "Cross Function"))
        .SelectMany(g => g)
        .Where(a =>
            (a.Service.Equals("IndustryX", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && a.Function != "IndustryX" && a.Function != "Cross Function") ||
            (a.Service.Equals("Song", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && a.Function != "Song" && a.Function != "Cross Function"))
        .ToList();


    return Ok(filteredAssets);
}

